# #include does not see the function definition

Tags: c, xcode5, header-files

I have a .c and .h file:

misc.c

```
#include "misc.h"




int isAllZeros(int *arr, int l)
{
    int i;
    int allZeros = 1;
    for (i = 0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i])
        {
            allZeros = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return allZeros;
}


int containsDup(int *arr1, int *arr2, int l1,int l2)
{
    int i,k;
    int dup = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<l1; i++)
    {
        for (k=0;k<l2;k++)
        {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[k])
            {
                dup = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (dup) break;
    }
    return dup;
}
```

and misc.h

```
#ifndef misc_h
#define misc_h

#include "ext.h"
#include "ext_obex.h"
#include "ext_path.h"

typedef struct _MNote {
    t_uint32 t;
    t_uint8 note, vel;
} t_MNote;

typedef struct _MPed {
    t_uint32 t;
    t_uint8 state;
} t_MPed;

typedef struct _Note {
    t_uint32 t, length;
    t_uint8 note, vel;
} t_Note;

typedef struct _chordInd {
    int length;
    int notes[5];
} t_chordInd;


int isAllZeros(int *arr, int l);

int containsDup(int *arr1, int *arr2, int l1,int l2);

#endif
```

In the main .c file the first line is  `#include "misc.h"`. It sees the structs declared in .h file but doesn't see the function definition in .c file. When I add `#include "misc.c"` To the main file it works, but why does it not work simply with .h?

Comment: Are both objects specified when linking?

Comment: Ack!  Do not `#include misc.c`.  The preprocessor looks at header files, and the linker links together object files to build an executable.  Try `gcc -c misc.c && gcc -c main.c && gcc misc.o main.o`  Let the compiler compile, and let the linker link.  (Unfortunately, `gcc` is the tool you use for both, so this confuses the issue somewhat.)

Comment: I am compiling in Xcode with a Build command, do I need to do anything extra?

Comment: On the surface, it looks as though `misc.c` is not being linked, as @cup and @WilliamPursell indicate. It would be beneficial to include in your question the text of the error that you are seeing.